# Do I have to declare an index signature in the following situations?

Tags: javascript, typescript

**Code with TypeScript.**

```
interface Object {
    number: number;
    string: string;
}

const object: Object = { number: 1, string: 'a' },
      object2 = {} as Object;

for (const key of Object.keys(object))
    object2[key] = object[key];
    => Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Object' has no index signature.
```

[URL for test](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Object%20%7B%0D%0A%09number%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09string%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20object%3A%20Object%20%3D%20%7B%20number%3A%201%2C%20string%3A%20'a'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%09%20%20object2%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20Object%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(const%20key%20of%20Object.keys(object))%0D%0A%09object2%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20object%5Bkey%5D%3B)

**Problem**

I've been doing TypeScript with a noImplicitAny option.

Basically, I guess it infer that `key` variable is key of both `object` and `object2`, so I think I don't have to declare an index signature.

But I thought wrong, so I always got a error about it.

Is there any way to fix the error without declaring an index signature?

Thanks for reading ! :)

Comment: This isn't directly relevant but I really would suggest naming your interface something other than `Object`, since that name collides with the global [`Object` interface from the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L110-L140).

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for suggestion! I never use that naming for in reality, but that's good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you want `Object.keys` to return `(keyof Obj)[]` rather than `string[]`. This has been discussed at some length, with probably the best source [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208). In short, Anders, the creator of Typescript, comments that:

> Once you move to the instantiated type world it degenerates because an object can (and often does) have more properties at run-time than are statically known at compile time.

So if `Object.keys` told you that it would only give you `number` and `string`, at runtime it could actually be different.

So if you want to continue using `Object.keys` then you will need to provide more explicit typings to tell TypeScript that everything is okay.

Comment: Thanks you :D. I got it. It helped a lot.